# Custom Labels like "R1"

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I want to have labels that are a composition of consecutive numbering combined with a static value (character). Something like R1, R2, ...

More specificly, I want to have a list of requirements, which I can then reference in the text as "R77", "R4.12" and so on

I have a theorem defined

```
\newtheoremstyle{requirement}%
{12pt}% Space above
{10pt}% Space below
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\large}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}% Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2:}\thmnote{ #3}}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{requirement}
\newtheorem{requirement}{Requirement}

\theoremstyle{requirement}
\newtheorem{subrequirement}{Requirement}[requirement]
```

This does the trick, and when I use it in my doc as

```
\begin{requirement}[my requirement]
\label{sec:requirements.requirement8}
some text
\end{requirement}
```

I have a nicely numbered label that I can reference via `\ref{...}`.
Now I want that numbering to have a letter "R" in front instead of simply a number. Can't find an option to solve this. Any suggestions?

Desired output would look something like this:

```
Requirement R2: xyz
bla

...

As defined in R2 ...
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\therequirement}{R\arabic{requirement}}` should work, after `\newtheorem` .... This will label the environment as well, of course. If this is not desired, we need more action. Please do not post such fragments only, in addition

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Seems NOT to work sadly. It outputs "R0[name]" (thats a zero after the R) and ignores everything defined in the theoremstyle. Moreover, all ref-commands just display the number of the chapter/section.

Comment: Then post a compilable example... having a small document my proposition works out of the box

Comment: Also using numbers (`8` here) in label names is not recommended -- it is error prone as soon as the order of environments etc. changes.

Comment: Ah apparently it's answered already ...

Comment: hmm - tried it again, now it works as you suggested. Funny. Thanks a lot anyhow :)

Comment: Natürlich funktioniert es ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
\renewcommand{\therequirement}{R\arabic{requirement}}% Add prefix to (sub-)requirements
```

after defining your `requirement` theorem. Since the `subrequirement` environment counter is defined to be "dependent" on the `requirement` counter, the prefix will be carried through to that environment counter as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{requirement}%
  {12pt}% Space above
  {10pt}% Space below
  {}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries\large}% Theorem head font
  {}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}% Space after theorem head
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2:}\thmnote{ #3}}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{requirement}
\newtheorem{requirement}{Requirement}
\newtheorem{subrequirement}{Requirement}[requirement]% subrequirement depends on requirement

\renewcommand{\therequirement}{R\arabic{requirement}}% Add prefix to (sub-)requirements

\begin{document}

\setcounter{requirement}{76}% Just for this example
\begin{requirement}[my requirement]
  \label{req:requirement}
  Some main requirement.
\end{requirement}

As defined in~\ref{req:requirement}, \ldots

\setcounter{requirement}{4}\setcounter{subrequirement}{11}% Just for this example
\begin{subrequirement}[my subrequirement]
  \label{req:subrequirement}
  Some sub-requirement.
\end{subrequirement}

As defined in~\ref{req:subrequirement}.

\end{document}
```